How to reconcile Luke 23:43 with the Apostle's Creed
Where did Jesus go when he died?
At the crucifixion, Jesus says to the other condemned man (Luke 23:43)

And Jesus said to him, “Truly I tell you, today you will be with Me in Paradise.”

The Apostle's Creed says:

who suffered under Pontius Pilate, was crucified, died, and was
buried, descended into hell, rose again from the dead on the third day,

If Jesus descended into hell until his resurrection, he could not have gone to Paradise on the same day. Is the Apostles' Creed wrong?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

First, we need to clarify terminologies, where

"hell" should be distinguished from hades (Greek) / sheol (Hebrew), and

paradise (as a temporary place) should be distinguished from

the "New Heaven and Earth" (our future place when our bodies are resurrected, which is NOT in existence yet) and from
"Heaven" as God's own realm (as in "Our Father who art in heaven").



See GotQuestions article What is the difference between Sheol, Hades, Hell, the lake of fire, Paradise, and Abraham's bosom?:

In the Hebrew Scriptures, the word used to denote the realm of the dead is sheol. It simply means “the place of the dead” or “the place of departed souls/spirits.” The New Testament Greek equivalent to sheol is hades, which is also a general reference to “the place of the dead.” Sheol/hades is divided into a place of blessing (where Lazarus was in Luke 16) and a place of torment (where the rich man was in Luke 16). Sheol also seems to be a temporary place where souls are kept as they await the final resurrection. The souls of the righteous, at death, go directly into the presence of God—the part of sheol called “heaven,” “paradise,” or “Abraham’s bosom” (Luke 23:43; 2 Corinthians 5:8; Philippians 1:23).

The Apostle's Creed refers to the Harrowing of Hell or more precisely "Hades" so we should not confuse temporary place Hades from the future "Hell" (or gehenna or the Lake of fire).  The Wikipedia article describes various traditional understandings on what exactly happened.  For example, in Catholicism

In his human soul united to his divine person, the dead Christ went down to the realm of the dead. He opened Heaven's gates for the just who had gone before him.

If we imagine multiple sections of Hades, on Holy Saturday Christ broke open the paradise section of Hades so the righteous dead (like Abraham, Moses, etc.) could enter, awaiting future resurrection of the body there, in the presence of God.
Therefore, a simple explanation is as follows: when both Jesus and the thief died on the same day, the thief joined the other righteous dead to enter paradise when, according to the Apostle's Creed, "Jesus descended to [hades]" to break open paradise.
We need not quibble about the meaning of "today", whether it should be Friday or Saturday (the day in the liturgical calendar when Jesus "descended into hell").  At any rate, the Apostle's Creed didn't specify a date either, so Jesus could have descended into hell on Friday.  But both the Biblical context and the Apostle's Creed context made it clear that it should have happened between the death and the resurrection of Jesus, NOT in the far future on the Day of Judgment.
Also, much more important is the application for our own deaths where ON THE SAME DAY (like the thief) we could also enter paradise into the presence of God, if we die in Christ.  This is an age-old interpretation, at least since St. Augustine.  See also GotQuestions article What did Jesus mean when He said, “Today you will be with me in paradise”? which addresses an alternate interpretation depending on comma placement.

Responding to the comment about the reference to Hades in Luke 16:19-31 where there is "a great chasm has been set in place" (v. 26), I think this interpretation where there are 2 sections in Hades (paradise and the rest) makes sense.  Remember, only Jesus could break open paradise (by virtue of his death on the cross), so it's a great enough unbridgeable gulf (consistent with Luke 16:26).  Keep in mind that the Bible doesn't intend to give us a precise geography of the "places" in the afterlife, which could be immaterial (!) with no literal spatial distance, making the word "chasm" (CSB) / "gulf" (KJV) to be metaphorical, intended to mean that there is no going to and fro between the sections.  What has been given in the Bible is sufficient information for our salvation.  What's unspecified in the Bible, various traditions try to fill in, but we don't need to believe them (including this answer).

There is a great gulf fixed between the rich man (in hades) and Lazarus (in paradise). Your answer seems to juxtapose them together into one place, separated, as it were, by a mere partition. Quote : the paradise section (sic) of hades : Unquote/

@NigelJ Yes, there is a great gulf fixed between the paradise section and other sections of hades since only Jesus could break open paradise, so it's great enough unbridgeable gulf, given that the Bible doesn't give us precise geography of the "places" in the afterlife (which could be immaterial with no concepts of spatial distance).  I do think my answer (aided by the exegesis given in the GotQuestion article) gives justice to all teachings about the intermediate state and the future fate of humankind.  What's unspecified in the Bible, various traditions try to fill.

It should be noted that this answer is based very much on Catholic teaching, and is not necessarily the view of "sola scriptura" and other denominations.

@RayButterworth sola scriptura simply means the primacy of scripture, allowing traditions to "fill in the blanks" or act as interpretation when the scriptural meaning is ambiguous.  But the Wikipedia shows how Eastern Orthodox has a similar understanding (the icon where Jesus pulled the hands of Adam and Eve to paradise), and the Evangelical GotQuestions shows Biblical consistency of my answer.

Looks like Jesus did not go to heaven that day because after he rose from the dead, he told Mary not touch him for he had not yet ascended to the Father. So my point is that the correct rendering of that verse is, I tell you today, you will be with me in paradise

@SoFewAgainstSoMany As pointed out in my answer, "paradise" shouldn't be confused with "heaven" (the realm of the Father).  After resurrection, Jesus ascended to "heaven", not to "paradise".  But prior to resurrection Jesus descended to "sheol" (where "paradise" is too).  John 20:17 is AFTER resurrection, so the meaning refers to "heaven" as his God-the-Father realm, not the same place he referred to in Luke 23:43.

Paradise is not in the underworld brother , citation is needed for that doctrine.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany That's the best understanding taking into account: 1) the need to reconcile Acts 2:31 (Jesus in hades) and Luke 23:43 (Jesus in paradise "today" with the invisible comma in the usual place, see GotQuestion article I recently added) and 2) what the 1st century people understand by "paradise" as Edenic place where God is present.  Why don't you answer the comma issue question yourself?
